# Is it possible to change inputbox icon in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, icons, inputbox

I have an inputbox which is called from code, yet while I have icons for all my forms, I don't get an icon on this inputbox. Since it's a standard option for messageboxes, I think it's weird there isn't a standard option for it concerning inputboxes.

So basically, how do I go at it to get an icon onto this inputbox?

`inventory = InputBox("Inventory:" & vbCrLf & "Make sure this is correct, as an error can cause failure to login.", "Edit Inventory", oldinv)`

Note: as this is a purely aesthetic problem, I haven't really researched this a lot because there's more important work to be done at this point.

Comment: Make your own InputBox. The one that comes with vb sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try my own inputbox

## THE INPUT FORM

```
Public Class frmInputbox

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    btnResponse.Text = MsgBoxResult.Ok
    Me.Hide()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    btnResponse.Text = MsgBoxResult.Cancel
    Me.Hide()
  End Sub

End Class
```

## THE WRAPPER

```
Public Class DrZedInputbox

  Private Shared _UserResponseDlg As New frmInputbox()

  Public Shared Function Inputbox(Prompt As String, Title As String, ByRef TextData As String, Left As Integer, Top As Integer, Icon As System.Drawing.Icon) As MsgBoxResult
    Inputbox = MsgBoxResult.Cancel
    _UserResponseDlg.Text = Title
    _UserResponseDlg.Label1.Text = Prompt
    _UserResponseDlg.TextBox1.Text = textData
    _UserResponseDlg.Left = Left
    _UserResponseDlg.Top = Top
    _UserResponseDlg.Icon = Icon
    _UserResponseDlg.ShowDialog()
    Inputbox = _UserResponseDlg.btnResponse.Text
  End Function

  Public Shared ReadOnly Property TextData As String
    Get
      Return _UserResponseDlg.TextBox1.Text
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Shared ReadOnly Property Response As MsgBoxResult
    Get
      Return CType(_UserResponseDlg.btnResponse.Text, MsgBoxResult)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Sub Dispose()
    _UserResponseDlg = Nothing
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    _UserResponseDlg = Nothing
    MyBase.Finalize()
  End Sub

End Class
```

## THE IMPLEMENTATION

To display the inputbox

```
DrZedInputbox.Inputbox("prompt", "title", "default", 100, 100, Me.Icon)
```

To collect the results (shown using a msgbox)

```
MsgBox("Text data entered: " & DrZedInputbox.TextData)
MsgBox("User response: " & DrZedInputbox.Response)
```

When finished with the inputbox (tidy up)

```
DrZedInputbox.Dispose()
```

## UPDATE

Added photo

[image: DrZed.Inputbox sample]

Comment: Please note: Additionally under the cancel button is another invisible button named btnResponse where i stored the results

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you would need to implement your own dialog for that (not supported natively). See:

- [InputBox Icon on vbcity](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/129813.aspx)

And other results on google with a similar advise.